# Convert an array of Integer into a single String

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I am having trouble finding how to easily build a string from an arrayList of Integer with Java 8, just like this :

> [3, 22, 1, 5] to "3 22 1 5"

For the moment I tried :

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/* ... */
String.join(" ", ((ArrayList<String>)(ids))); //cast do not work

List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/* ... */
String.join(" ", ids.forEach(id -> Integer.toString(id))); //forEach returns void so it throws an error
```

Anyone does have a convenient/elegant solution ?

Thanks anyone & have a nice day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using Streams

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/* ... */
String joined= ids.stream()
                   .map(i -> i.toString())
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable..
You can't append element to it

In this case, i would use **StringBuilder**

With **StringBuilder** you can append element :

```
    int[] myArr = {4,3,4,53,2};
    StringBuilder myStringB = new StringBuilder();
    String myString = new String();

    for (int i : myArr) {
        myStringB.append(i);
    }

    myString = myStringB.toString();
```

Comment: Instead of `StringBuilder` we can use `StringJoiner` which automatically places delimiter (here space) between added elements. Demo: https://ideone.com/onybOm

Answer (score 1):

You were almost ready with the solution, just that you need to supply the proper arguments.

If you look at the `public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements)` method signature it takes a `delimiter` and an `iterable`. You were almost close to joining the strings using this method, all you had to do is to provide an `Iterable<String>`.

Since you start with a `List<Integer>` you need to convert it to an `Iterable<String>` to do that you can use the below code:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `ids` is a `List<Integer>`. Note that you need to do a `map(String::valueOf)` as you start with a `List<Integer>` not with a `List<String>`. Now that you have an `Iterable<String>` you can use that as the second argument of `String.join()`.

So the complete solution is:

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
ids.add(1);
ids.add(2);
ids.add(3);

Iterable<String> iterable = ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
String result = String.join(" ", iterable);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

If the `ids` may contain `null` then you can filter it out before applying the `map()`:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = ids.stream()
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .map(String::valueOf)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters for you or if you have a very large list I would recommend using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and Java Streams to collect all numbers:

```
String joined = ids.stream()
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                (s, i) -> s.append(" ").append(i), 
                (s1, s2) -> s1.append(" ").append(s2))
        .substring(1);
```

This prepends a `" "` to all numbers. To get the final result we can use [`StringBuilder.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring-int-) to cut off the first white space.

To improve the performance on large lists you can also use [`List.parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) or [`Stream.parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) to create a parallel stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use StringBuilder then you can you the following simple for loop:

```
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ids.add(3);
    ids.add(22);
    ids.add(1);
    ids.add(5);

    String st = "";

    for(int i = 1; i <= ids.size(); i++) {
        st += String.valueOf(ids.get(i-1));
        if(i != ids.size()) {
            st += " ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(st);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`String numberString = ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`